# Error handling for Stripe credit card processing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, e-commerce

I have a rails application that uses Stripe for credit card processing. Currently several exceptions are being handled anywhere a transaction takes place. The code below is being used currently in 11 places. In all places it is essentially the same with the exception of the message being passed to `stripe_error`. Is it possible to create a reusable piece of code that can be used in all these places?

```
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(@purchase.stripe_charge_id)
  resp = charge.capture(amount: fee.cancellation_fee,
                        receipt_email: @customer.email)
  @purchase.update_attributes(
    accepted_charge: true,
    stripe_transaction_id: resp['balance_transaction']
  )
  logger.info("Charged customer for cancellation #{@customer.id} #{@purchase.total_fee}")
  event('cancellation_charge', 'purchase_id', @purchase.id,
        fee: @purchase.total_fee, customer_id: @purchase.customer_id,
        provider_id: @purchase.provider_id)
  purchase_set_md5(@purchase.id)
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation', fee.cancellation_fee)
  @purchase.update_attributes(
    accepted_charge: false,
    charge_errors: message,
    stripe_transaction_id: '',
    status: "Cancellation fee charge did not go through #{@err['message']}"
  )
  purchase_set_md5(@purchase.id)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation_invalid_request', fee.cancellation_fee)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation_authentication', fee.cancellation_fee)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation_api_connect', fee.cancellation_fee)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation_generic error', fee.cancellation_fee)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
rescue => e
  @err = stripe_error(e, 'cancellation_something_else', fee.cancellation_fee)
  render :err_show, status: :payment_required, json: @err
  return
end
```

#### stripe_error

```
  def stripe_error(e, charge_type, fee = 0)
    logger.error("e #{e}")
    err = {
      charge_type: charge_type,
      errcode: ERR_STRIPE_ERR,
      message: "#{e}"
    }
    event(charge_type, 'error', "#{e}")
    logger.error("Charging error on #{charge_type} purchase for #{fee} ")
    logger.error("type #{e} ")
    err
  end
```

Comment: Do these exceptions inherit from a Stripe exception base? You could catch that base, and check for the `is_a?` of the exception later to change the string you use when you forward it

Comment: [Stripe API for Ruby](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby)

Comment: I'm sure this can be simplified, but the solution would probably involve  the `stripe_error`  method does, which isn't included in the code posted.

Comment: @Flambino I've update the post with `stripe_error` code . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step would be to separate out actually rendering the error message from rescueing the exceptions:

```
def render_errors(errors, template: :err_show,  status: :payment_required)
  render template, status: status, json: errors
end
```

Then can you group the majority of the exceptions:

```
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError, 
       Stripe::AuthenticationError
       Stripe::APIConnectionError,
       Stripe::StripeError => e

render_errors( stripe_error(e) )
```

A good idea would be then to separate generating the errors and logging them.